# substitution of lpc in python to estimate formants frequency

Tags: python, frequency

I wanted to use

```
from scikits.talkbox.linpred.levinson_lpc import lpc
```

to estimate formants, but it didn't work in python3

what can be the substitution of lpc?
or is there an example code for estimation of formants frequency in python?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a look to AudioLazy:

- Github: https://github.com/danilobellini/audiolazy
- Documentation: https://pythonhosted.org/audiolazy/lazy_lpc.html

You should find the required functions to solve your python 3 issue.